# Excel VBA Extract Date From Filename

Tags: excel, string, vba, date, pattern-matching

I am using the following, to get the filename.

```
Dim wbName As String
wbName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
```

Some of the filenames might look like this:

"CM CC Tracking Log FY 17-18-08.07.17" 
"Tracking Log 10-23-17" 
"Tracking Log 17-18 Car Club USA - 8-7-17"

I am trying to figure out how to extract the date string, pattern match using regex.

08.07.17 
10-23-17 
8-7-17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this pattern:

```
\b(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[-./](3[01]|[1-2]\d|0?[1-9])[-./](\d{2}|\d{4})\b
```

This assumes the dates, as you show in your example,

- are in the MDY format,
- M can be either a single or a double digit entry in the range of 1-12 with an optional leading `0` for 1 to 9
- D will be in the range of 1-31 with an optional leading 0 for 1 to 9
- Y will be either two digits or four digits

The separator will be in the set of `[-./]`

In case you require it, the M D and Y will be in separate capture groups.

If that does not sufficiently describe things, you will need to be more specific.  It would be easy to modify so that all the separators are the same, for example.

Comment: I used this for my pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This regex will capture all of the date formats you mentioned. Make sure it is a `global`:

```
(\d{1,2}[.,-]\d{1,2}[.,-]\d{1,2})
```

Comment: I just realized that you would have a priority issue, but with the examples you posted, it seems all of the dates are at the end of your file names, so simply use the `Right(filename, 8)` function to first get the proper substring and then apply the regex on it. This way it is for sure the answer will be accurate. It will be hard to include everything in the regex